Is their a way to have a forever loop and a wait in js?
I'm trying to make clones forever but wait a bit before every clone but I can't find a way to do this.
  function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
 
while (true){
  // Clone the image with id "bullet"
sleep(2000).then(() => {const originalBullet = document.getElementById("bullet");
const clonedBullet = originalBullet.cloneNode(true);
document.body.appendChild(clonedBullet);

// Set random y position and specific x position
clonedBullet.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * (450 - 250 + 1)) + 250;
clonedBullet.style.left = "0px";

// Move the cloned image to the right until it reaches the edge
const moveInterval = setInterval(() => {
    const rect = clonedBullet.getBoundingClientRect();
    if (rect.right >= window.innerWidth) {
        clearInterval(moveInterval); // Stop moving
        document.body.removeChild(clonedBullet); // Delete the clone
    } else {
        clonedBullet.style.left = (rect.left + 1) + "px"; // Move right
    }
}, 5); });.


}

This is what I did, but it infact did not work.

It seems you already know about setInterval, why not use it?

If you want a while (true) loop, you need to await something in the loop body. Don't use .then().

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function cloneBullets() {
    while (true) {
        // Wait for 2000 milliseconds (2 seconds)
        await sleep(2000);

        // Clone the image with id "bullet"
        const originalBullet = document.getElementById("bullet");
        if (originalBullet) {
            const clonedBullet = originalBullet.cloneNode(true);
            document.body.appendChild(clonedBullet);

            // Set random y position and specific x position
            clonedBullet.style.position = 'absolute';
            clonedBullet.style.top = Math.floor(Math.random() * (450 - 250 + 1)) + 250 + 'px';
            clonedBullet.style.left = "0px";

            // Move the cloned image to the right until it reaches the edge
            const moveInterval = setInterval(() => {
                const rect = clonedBullet.getBoundingClientRect();
                if (rect.right >= window.innerWidth) {
                    clearInterval(moveInterval); // Stop moving
                    document.body.removeChild(clonedBullet); // Delete the clone
                } else {
                    clonedBullet.style.left = (rect.left + 1) + "px"; // Move right
                }
            }, 5);
        }
    }
}

// Start the cloning process
cloneBullets();

This should do it by making the function asynchronous and using await, the loop will then pause for the specified duration before each iteration. You could also look at CSS animations to do this, might be overall easier.

Thanks I did not think about doing that!

@FAKEACOUNT if this has solved the problem then please mark this answer as answered.
